# find() and attr() in prototypejs

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

What are equivalent of jQuery function find() and attr() in prototypejs?

Could someone help me to convert this code using prototypejs?

```
var className = $(this).find('.myBtn').attr('class');
$(this).find('.tab').attr('class', className + ' current');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I use jQuery. The existing code is using prototypejs and I have to tweak it.

Comment: Prototype isn't bad. Its just well structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.down()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/down/) to find a descendant and [`readAttribute()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/readAttribute/)/[`writeAttribute()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/writeAttribute/) to read/modify attributes.

Or you could simply stay with jQuery. ;)

Comment: Element.select() is more similar as stated by the other answer, as it finds all the elements matching, while .down() only the first N matching.

Comment: As stated above .down() only finds the first one, not all matching descendants

Answer (score 11):

For others searching and landing here: I think Prototype's [`Element.select()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/prototype/select/index.html) would be a better fit as a jQuery `$.find()` equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

There is a notable difference between prototype select() and down(). When ever you use select() , it will return the result wrapped in an array object. But if you use down() , the selected element ( given that there is only a unique element ) will result in that element.

[image]

Comment: If you had also answered the part about reading and modifying attributes, I would say this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('element_id').readAttribute('attribute_name'); //- returns the value
$('element_id').writeAttribute('attribute_name', 'new value'); // writes the value
```

http://api.prototypejs.org has a nice and succinct set of documentation, it's really worth a read. Prototype has a very disciplined approach to working with the page, and to working within data, much of the latter stolen liberally from Ruby's Enumerable module. jQuery + Underscore equals Prototype.